Quick way to organize and delete local stashes
I want to stash my changes, but I often have temporary stashes that accumulate, which I want to delete. I also have important stashes, so "drop all" isn't an option.
Deleting stashes one by one in the VSCode UI takes too long. I'm looking for a more convenient method.


It sounds like you are overusing stashes. A stash is basically an anonymous branch, whose lifespan isn't intended to last longer than one or two intervening commands. You should get into the habit of creating actual branches, or deleting your stashes sooner.

Here's a workaround. For important stash entries, you can create branches, tags (more recommended), or other kinds of refs on them.
# Create tags that start with stash_ for example.
git tag stash_foo stash@{0}

# Or an annotated tag which also has a tag message to describe more
git tag stash_foo stash@{0} -m "tag message"

And then you can use drop all.
To apply a tagged stash entry,
git stash apply stash_foo

A side effect is that you can push and fetch the tagged stash entry between repositories.

Wow, I had no idea you could tag a stash. The wonders of Git continue!
